# converting a simple jquery code to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code for a simple photo gallery that had been writen with jquery, but i think it's overkill to load the entire library for such a simple thing. I want it in raw javascript.

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Also i'm wondering how do I attach a loading spinner to this code. thanks.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xVNEX/)

Comment: There's a reason why jQuery's motto is *Write less, do more*: the plain Javascript code equivalent to your excerpt will probably weight at least a few dozen lines, more if you want it to be cross-browser. I'd suggest you avoid reinventing the wheel and include the library, it's not that heavyweight.

Comment: Quick answer: It's not overkill to load jQuery.
Longer answer: The code you pasted is using event delegation to bind a single event to #thumbs which acts on all of its child img elements.  This is exactly what libraries are good at, it eliminates the need to write a ton of boilerplate code to do this.  This 4 line snippet of code could end up being 50+ if you wrote it out in native JS.  I'm not even sure where to begin though.

Comment: These are valid answers ;) why not post them  ?

Comment: @Nix: On their own, I'd say they aren't (but they're *great* comments). The OP has clearly said "I don't want to use a library for this" so the answer "Use a library" is, well, incorrect. (But again, completely agree with the comments.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder :  If he states a reason not to use a library, and you feel he is misguided, then it is absolutely a valid answer.

Comment: @Nix: We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @NL500: *"Also i'm wondering how do I attach a loading spinner to this code. thanks."* Recommend posting that as a separate question. Compound questions don't tend to get good answers to all their compound parts.

Comment: Point of note: the fact that this is a *photo gallery* and you need a *loading spinner* indicates that the overhead of jQuery (70K or so) is already inconsequential compared to the entire purpose of your application: to load *images* -- each of which is probably much larger than jQuery. "Overkill" is rewriting well tested, established code for no purpose other than saving a few bytes (that are probably already cached at your users' browsers anyway). You introduce substantial risks (e.g. browser incompatibilities) for no substantive benefit.

Comment: @jamietre: ***Excellent*** point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without using any library, it looks a bit like this, although of course there are other ways to write it:

```
(function() {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage'),
        description = document.getElementById('description');

    document.getElementById('thumbs').onclick = handleGalleryClick;

    function handleGalleryClick(event) {
        var target;

        event = event || window.event;                // Handle IE difference
        target = event.target || event.srcElement;    // Another one
        if (target && target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "IMG") {
            largeImage.src = target.src.replace('thumb', 'large');
            description.innerHTML = target.getAttribute('alt');
        }
    }
})();
```

Make sure that script appears at the bottom of your page (just before the closing `body` element) or wrap it up in a `window.onload` although you won't be happy with how long that takes to occur, as `window.onload` happens after all images and such are loaded.

**But**: I have to agree with Frédéric's and John's comments: It's not overkill to load a library for this, and in the case of jQuery (and Prototype and YUI) you can [load via the Google CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/) and use something your page visitor probably already has in their cache anyway.

---

**Update**: In the comments below, [scunliffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6144/scunliffe) pointed out an IE bug that [I've blogged in the past](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) that could affect the above, which is magically worked around for you by jQuery. So I thought it might be useful to flag up the various complications that this simple little script has that a good library will sort out for you:

- **`addEventListener` vs. `attachEvent`**: IE6 through IE8 don't support the DOM2 standard `addEventListener`, using Microsoft's own `attachEvent` instead. I actually punted on this in the above for simplicity and just used the DOM0 `onclick = ...` style, but there's a good reason *not* to do that: With the DOM0 style, you can only have a single event listener per event per element, and attaching another will detach the previous one. So my code above doesn't play nicely with others, because it will dislodge any previous DOM0 `click` handler (and will be dislodged by a DOM0 `click` handler attached after the code above runs).
- **Accessing the `event` object**: The [DOM standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) says that the `event` object is passed into the event handler as its first argument. IE, instead, uses a global `window.event` object. That's the reason for my first "IE difference" above.
- **Properties on the `event` object**: ...and similarly, the [DOM standard says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event) the actual element on which the event was fired will be the `target` property. IE6 through IE8 use `srcElement` instead. (There are other differences, too.) Hence my "Another one" comment.
- **Bug workaround**: This is the [conflation](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) thing scunliffe pointed out. The above relies on `document.getElementById` to work correctly, but on IE6 and IE7, it doesn't. It conflates several namespaces rather than working just with `id` values.

...so all in all, this simple little script makes the point fairly well that libraries in general — and a *good* library in particular — can save you time, keep your site broadly-compatible, and are just generally worth their little cost. I don't know about the others, but for instance jQuery works around the conflation bug for you, but another well-known and well-respected library, Prototype, does not.

*(Side note: Before we knock Microsoft too much, let's remember that `attachEvent` and `srcElement` probably predate the DOM2 spec; Microsoft did a lot of innovating in IE5.5 and IE6. [They invented [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), for instance.] IE6 was — by **far** — the best browser available in 2001, due apologies to Opera. That said, IE6 came out after the standard did and so adding the standards stuff at that point, or several years later in IE7, **might** have been a worthwhile thing to do! But IE9 fixes a lot of this stuff.)*

Comment: Wouldn't the click event actually be on the children img elements of #thumbs?... And also would it not be on all future children img elements... Not just existing?

Comment: @scunliffe - to implement `delegate`, you have to listen on the root container and check to see if the event target was an `<img>` (so the event works on current and _future_ elements).

Comment: @scunliffe: `click` bubbles from child elements up through their parents, etc., up to the root (unless stopped). So by hooking `click` on the `thumbs` container, we're handling all of the `img` elements within it (now and in the future when others are added). This is how jQuery's `delegate` works, it's just (handy) syntactic sugar for standard event delegation, which is what I've done above.

Comment: Ah, yes I missed that you were filtering later on only images... Ignore my itchy trigger finger ;-)

Comment: Actually there's one more reason why using jQuery here would be helpful.  If this page has a `<meta name="description" content="My Gallery" />` type tag this code **will fail in IE** due to a *bug* that jQuery auto-handles for you. http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-152-getelementbyid-returns.html jQuery nicely avoids IE's ID vs. Name bug to ensure you get the correct element every time.

Comment: @scunliffe: Good point, I've also [written up that namespace conflation bug](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html). I think I'll add a postscript with all the things that jQuery is handling that we'll have to handle ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. After reading the post and all the comments, I decided to use the jquery approach instead of using pure javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You call it simple, but it's doing somewhat advanced things. To emulate `delegate`, you have to attach a click listener on the root container and check for clicks on any `<img>` tag.

Not to mention you have to do things like use `attachEvent` in IE instead of `addEventListener`

The code would look something like (untested):

```
function listen(root, callback) {
    var addEvent = 'attachEvent';
    if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') {
        addEvent = 'addEventListener';
    }

    root[addEvent](function (e) {
        if (/img/i.test(e.target.tagName)) {
            callback.apply(e.target);
        }
    }, false);
}

listen(document.getElementById('thumbs'), function () {
    document.getElementById('largeImage').src = this.src.replace(/thumb/ig, 'large');
    document.getElementById('description').src = this.alt;
});
```

In fact, as TJ's post shows below, I'm not even handling all of the IE idiosyncrasies. jQuery is not overkill considering all of the browser headaches it solves for you.